# namespacing a php file with no class

Tags: php, namespaces

Can a php file have a namespace without a class?

For example:

```
<?php namespace x\y\z; ?> 
<html>
..html code mixed with php function calls
</html>
```

Then can that code be called from another php file using the namespace?

Comment: Why didn't you just try it?

Comment: How would I try it?  There's no class or function to call. That's why I was asking. If there was some sort of anonymous way to call non-named functions via file name.  Php has so much stuff you never know what's possible.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Namespaces only affect classes, interfaces, functions and constants. No other code is affected by namespaces. Namespaces are a mechanism to prevent naming collisions; since HTML blocks are not "named" there's nothing to namespace.